# Add Bootstrap js plugins to brunch-config.js to use as front-end assets?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, npm, brunch

I want to use Bootstrap's `alert.js` plugin as a front-end asset, but can not figure out how to make it work using `brunch-config.js` and `npm`.

At the moment I have such brunch config (it adds `jQuery` and Bootstrap css to assets):

```
exports.config = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },

  paths: {
    watched: [
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],

    public: "priv/static"
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "jquery", "bootstrap"],
    globals: {
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    },
    styles: {
      bootstrap: ['dist/css/bootstrap.css']
    }
  }
};
```

Plugin file is here - `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/umd/alert.js`.

One more thing: with this config `Brunch` actually does something and adds to `/js/app.js` the needed `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/boostrap.js` file which already contains the `Alert` plugin.

`jQuery` works properly, Bootstrap css works also. The only problem - Bootstrap js plugins (there are no warnings in console).

In my `package.json` I have this version of Bootstrap:

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "brunch": "~2.1.3",
    "clean-css-brunch": "~1.8.0",
    "css-brunch": "~1.7.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "~1.8.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `require("bootstrap");` to the end of `app.js` solved the problem for me. I'm far from understanding brunch / bootstrap properly, but AFAIK the javascript side of bootstrap is just a collection of plugins for jQuery. Requiring bootstrap adds the plugins to the global `jQuery` object (already presented in your `brunch-config.js`).